# skip the next instruction in c code

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

Hi every one : I try to skip instruction

```
void func(char *str) { 
   char buffer[24]; 
   int *ret; 
   strcpy(buffer, str); 
} 

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
  int x;
  x = 0;
  func(argv[1]);
  x = 1; 
  printf("%d\n”, x); 
}
```

How I can use the pointer `*ret` defined in `funct()` to modify the return address for the function in such away I can skip `x=1`

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can add an `if (1==0)` before `x=1;`... then it'll skip `x=1`.

Comment: What's wrong with `if (cond) x = 1;` or `x = cond ? 1 : x;` ?

Comment: It appears that the OP is trying to modify the stack for achieving a "hacked" return. If that is correct, then C is AFAIK not going to solve the issue - inlined asm would.

Comment: Not even considering that this is CPU-dependent, optimization-dependent and compiler-dependent.

Comment: I want to use the overflow problem in the code ... " change the return address in the stack "

Answer (score 2):

**It's a bad idea to use this in production code!** (Reasons copied from dvnrrs' comment.) This is undefined behavior; it is severely abusing (assumed) knowledge about the way the stack is laid out under the hood, and the size of the compiled instructions. This is doomed to failure, especially if optimization is turned on.

Please note that modifying the memory next to local variables this way is incorrect C code, and it makes undefined behavior. I think there is no standard C solution to your problem, so if you want to do that, your best bet is architecture-specific assembly code. The following code happens to work for me in C on i386 with my GCC, but it's still undefined behavior, so it's inherently fragile and can cease to work in any changes in the compiler or in the ABI.

This prints 42 for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(char *str) {
  (&str)[-1] += 2;
} 

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
  (void)argc; (void)argv;
  int x;
  x = 42;
  func(argv[1]);
  x = 137; 
  printf("%d\n",x); 
  return 0;
}
```

Compile and run on Linux i386:

```
$ gcc -m32 -W -Wall -s -O0 t.c && ./a.out
42
```

Comment: This is undefined behavior; you're severely abusing (assumed) knowledge about the way the stack is laid out under the hood, and the size of the compiled instructions. This is doomed to failure, especially if optimization is turned on.

Comment: @dvnrrs: Sure, but the question explicitly asks for such a solution, see the buffer-overflow tag.

Comment: ... which one should absolutely not do under any circumstances; there's no reason whatsoever to write code like this!

Comment: @dvnrrs: Learning about buffer overflows is one possible reason.

Comment: Granted, but in that case, the question would/should have been asked entirely differently.

Comment: I've added a disclaimer to the beginning of my answer. Please reconsider your vote.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44015/discussion-between-dvnrrs-and-pts)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in C; the closest thing would be [the `setjmp()` and `longjmp()` functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setjmp.h) but those won't work for your exact case.

As others pointed out in comments, the best thing to do might be to give your function a return value, and then check that return value in the caller to decide what code to run next. Your sample code seems like a contrived test case so I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish.